# Qt: drop down menu size

Tags: qt, qtwidgets

I have a drop down menu inside a [QMenuBar](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmenubar.html), the menu contains many actions.
How could I increase the size of these actions?

Which is visually make the drop down menu appears larger?

Comment: Larger in which direction?

Comment: The height to be larger.

Comment: `QMenu` is a `QWidget` - you can resize it